# Launching a TornadoFX App from (an existing) Kotlin program

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    HelloWorldApp().launch()
}

fun App.launch() {
    JFXPanel()
    Platform.runLater({
        start(Stage())
    })
}
```

This is what I do right now. Is there a better? more succinct way?

Is it safe to run multiple different TornadoFX apps from within the same kotlin program this way? I read something somewhere about a global variable so I'm wondering if only 1 is allowed/recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM already knows how to start JavaFX applications, and since your App class extends `tornadofx.App` which again extends `javafx.application.Application`, you can simply point your JVM to that main class and it will run just fine. If you want to explicitly launch your TornadoFX application, JavaFX provides a static `launch` method you should use.

A typical main function that starts a JavaFX or TornadoFX application would be:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(HelloWorldApp::class.java, *args)
}
```

JavaFX only allows the `Application.launch` function to be called one time in the life of a JVM, so you can't really start more than one anyways. However, TornadoFX provides special OSGi support allowing you to actually stop and relaunch other TornadoFX apps in the same JVM by utilizing an application proxy instance.

TornadoFX also supports JPro by using Scopes, which allows multiple application instance, though without actually calling `Application.launch` several times.

Comment: I read that `Application.launch()` in the docs can only be run once... and it also won't execute the next line after it. For example, put a `println("something)` and you won't see that text printed - I guess I wasn't being specific enough in my title.. I meant from an existing Kotlin program. thanks for the explanation though

Comment: Yes, that's how it works - you're only supposed to call it once, but you can do that from anywhere, at any time. You can wrap the call in a Thread if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can start it like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<HelloWorldApp>(args)
}
```

The `launch` function is defined in `tornadofx` package as a top-level function, `HelloWorldApp` is a random `Application` class.